# Can the new Spring Authorization Server generate tokens other than JWT and Opaque?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-resource-server, spring-authorization-server

I am currently migrating the authorization server from old `Spring Security OAuth2` to the new `Spring Authorization Server`.

It seems that the new `Spring Authorization Server` generates JWT tokens by default.

What if I dont want to use JWT and Opaque.

Is it possible to generate tokens same as the old `Spring Security OAuth2`?

By the way, I also dont have idea what type of token the old `Spring Security OAuth2` generates...i am a noob here...any idea is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What about using something more "noob" friendly as authorization-server (like Keycloak or an SaaS OpenID provider like Auth0)? You'll get advanced features like identity federation (Google, Facebook, etc.), multi-factor authentication, connectors to LDAP or existing user DB, etc. You then [configure your Spring REST API as resource-server](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers)

Comment: I think opaque token it is. I misunderstand the idea of opaque tokens, but with few examples, I conclude that its the opaque token that I need.

Comment: "Opaque" is from the resource-server point of view: it is considered a black-box and introspection on authorization-server is needed for validation and to get token details (claims)

Answer (score 2):

You can generate any type of token you want, using [`OAuth2TokenGenerator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-generator), though it sounds like you don't have another type in mind.

Spring Authorization Server supports `OAuth2TokenFormat.SELF_CONTAINED` and `OAuth2TokenFormat.REFERENCE` as types, which are high level categories that map concretely to JWT and Opaque respectively. If you aren't interested in using a JWT, then I suggest using Opaque. It is quite simple to configure and use.

If you want to use another self-contained format, there are many areas of the framework you will need to customize and get right, which might be difficult without a spec. I don't remember off hand what formats were supported by the old project, but it was likely one or both of these.

Comment: hi steve, thanks for your reply, I finally figure it out that I will have to use opaque tokens. But I encounter problems in my implementation. When using opaque tokens I always get `Internal Server Error` when making GET request to the resource server. There is no problem in generating the tokens, it is only that I cannot access the resource server.

Comment: Sorry to hear that your resource server isn't working. I recommend playing around with the [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples) first, and configure them to use opaque tokens. If generating tokens is working, you can configure [opaque tokens](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html) in the resource server via the [introspection endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/protocol-endpoints.html#oauth2-token-introspection-endpoint).